# FileNotFoundException not being thrown

Tags: java, try-catch, filenotfoundexception

I am writing a piece of code that returns a scanner for a user-input file name. Here's the code:

```
public static Scanner getInputScanner(Scanner console) {
    System.out.print("Enter input file: ");
    String fileName = "";
    try {
        fileName = console.nextLine();
        File f = new File(fileName);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {      
        while (!(new File(fileName)).exists()) {
            System.out.println(fileName + " (No such file or directory)");
            System.out.print("Enter input file: ");
            fileName = console.nextLine();
        }
    }
    File f = new File(fileName);
    return new Scanner(f);
}
```

I am getting two errors:

```
Compression.java:49: error: exception FileNotFoundException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {      
      ^
Compression.java:57: error: unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
    return new Scanner(f);
```

I can't figure out why the try block isn't throwing an exception, since the user could input an invalid file name.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: changed the FileNotFoundException to a NullPointerException and that fixed the first problem. Now, however, I get an error that my return statement is throwing an unreported FileNotFoundException. But this code wouldn't execute unless the file is valid, right? Is Java blind to this, and requires I catch the exception anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File(java.lang.String)) clearly states that the `File(String pathname)` constructor can only throw `NullPointerException` and NOT `FileNotFoundException`.

If you want to see if the file name is valid, use [`f.exists()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists()).

Answer (score 1):

The `FileNotFoundException` is neither thrown by [Scanner#nextLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--) nor by creating a new `File` object ([File#new(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File-java.lang.String-)). Both functions do nothing that is related to file I/O.

- `Scanner.nextLine()` operates on an alread existing input source
- `File#new()` creates simply a new `File` object that points (file name) to an (maybe existing) actual file.

The creation of a [new `Scanner` object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner-java.io.File-) in contrast, involves creating a new `InputStream`, so it actually touches the supplied file by opening it.

From *java.util.Scanner*:

```
public Scanner(File source) throws FileNotFoundException {
    this((ReadableByteChannel)(new FileInputStream(source).getChannel()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 return new Scanner(f);
```

throws error when file is not found, it can't return the `scanner(f)` . so should be wrapped in `try-catch` block.

or you need to make the `getInputScanner` to throw the `FileNotFoundException`

Answer (score 0):

```
File f = new File(fileName);
```

does *not* throw an exception if the file does not exist. A `File` object is really just a filename; it does not refer to the actual file. If the file does not exist, you will get an exception when you try to use it.

`new Scanner(f)` is the part that throws a `FileNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 0):

You can always call [`File.exists()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29) before you construct your `Scanner` and if you use an infinite loop you can simplify your logic and eliminate those errors. Something like,

```
public static Scanner getInputScanner(Scanner console) {
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Enter input file: ");
        String fileName = console.nextLine();
        File f = new File(fileName);
        if (!f.exists()) {
            System.out.println(fileName + " (No such file or directory)");
            continue;
        }
        try {
            return new Scanner(f);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // This shouldn't happen.
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(fileName + " (No such file or directory)");
        }
    }
}
```